# apt failing to install due to connection failure to source which isn't in /etc/apt/sources.list

Tags: apt, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

Apt can't install anything as it failes with an error of "Temporary failure resolving 'raspbian.playstar.se'". Updates run fine.
I have an empty `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, and the default `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Is there another place where apt gets source urls which it tries?

Comment: The Raspbian entry in sources.list points to a mirror director. In your case it resolves to the raspbian.playstar.se. The problem may be temporary one so I would try again in a couple of hours time...

Comment: @Dirk That's good to know, thank you! However it's sadly not temporary, I've already waited a couple days before asking the question. Can I set it to a mirror of choice?

Comment: Hard code a (nearby) server from the list at https://raspbian.org/RaspbianMirrors to replace http://mirrordirector....

Comment: Thanks @Dougie, that fixes it! If you add it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get over bad repos by hard coding an address from https://raspbian.org/RaspbianMirrors.

It's not intended as a permanent option, but will get you going right now.